Permission issue when using SSL certificates with PostgreSQL in CI/CD pipeline
I'm encountering an issue with permissions while attempting to use SSL certificates with a PostgreSQL container in my CI/CD pipeline. Here's the setup:
I have a Docker Compose file defining a PostgreSQL service with SSL enabled:
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:latest
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=postgres
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    networks:
      - my-network
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - db:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ../../../bin/certs/postgres:/ssl
    command:
      [
        "postgres",
        "-c",
        "ssl=on",
        "-c",
        "ssl_cert_file=/ssl/server.crt",
        "-c",
        "ssl_key_file=/ssl/server.key",
      ]
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD-SHELL", "pg_isready -U postgres"]
      interval: 5s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 5


volumes:
  db:
    driver: local

networks:
  my-network:
    driver: bridge
    name: my-network


I'm generating self-signed SSL certificates using a Makefile target:
.PHONY: generate-ssl
gen-ssl: ## Generates a self signed ssl certificates
    @mkdir -p $(OUTPUT_DIR); \
    openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout $(OUTPUT_DIR)/server.key -out $(OUTPUT_DIR)/server.crt -sha256 -days 365 -nodes -subj "/CN=localhost"; \
    chmod 600 $(OUTPUT_DIR)/server.key;

When I tested in local using everything working fine
make gen-ssl
docker-compose up

Locally, everything works fine. However, when I run this in my CI/CD pipeline (GitHub Actions), I encounter the following error:
waiting for server to start....FATAL:  private key file "/ssl/server.key" must be owned by the database user or root
I understood this is because of permission issue but couldn't find out the solution, how to fix it>

What does ls -l say on your local machine for the folder where the keys are?

-rw-r--r--  1 srinivas  staff      1805 Apr  1 20:43 server.crt
-rw-r-----  1 root      staff      3268 Apr  1 20:43 server.key
